# Change polyline color for individual legs in Google Maps API v3 generated by DirectionsRenderer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a DirectionsResult which displays on the map.  How do I access individual polyLines (legs) and change color when user double clicks on a marker generated by DirectionsRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use different colors for particular legs, the route is a single polyline.

You must draw the route on your own, separate polylines for each leg, then you be able to apply different colors for legs.

Comment: I strongly feel they to add that to the API - "Access to waypoints in a route and allow customization of leg and markers draw by DirectionsRenderer".

Comment: Is your question about programming or about feelings?

Comment: You can create a [feature/enhancement request in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no way of changing colors for particular legs but there is a non-efficient way of doing this.

Here is what I tried,

```
function handleResponse(result, status){
    console.log(result);
    var modifiedResult;
    var displayDirection;
    var line;
    var countTotalRoutes = 0;

    var pinkLine = {
        strokeColor: '#ff0089',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 5
    };

    var blackLine = {
        strokeColor: '#333',
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 5
    };

    var whiteLine = {
        strokeColor: '#3367d6',
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 5
    };

    var lineColor = [pinkLine, blackLine, whiteLine];

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        for(var i = 0; i < result.routes[0].legs.length; i++){
            modifiedResult = $.extend(true, {}, result);
            modifiedResult.request = result.request;
            modifiedResult.geocoded_waypoints = [];
            modifiedResult.geocoded_waypoints.push(result.geocoded_waypoints[i]);
            modifiedResult.geocoded_waypoints.push(result.geocoded_waypoints[i+1]);
            modifiedResult.routes[0].legs = [result.routes[0].legs[i]];
            line = lineColor[countTotalRoutes % 3];

            displayDirection = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({polylineOptions : line, suppressMarkers : true, preserveViewport : true});

            displayDirection.setMap(map);
            displayDirection.setDirections(modifiedResult);
            countTotalRoutes += 1;

            modifiedResult = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is the best working solution i found about setting colour for each "leg"